# Django Rest Framework Multiple Model Serializtion

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am using Django Rest Framework to make and API. I have and endpoint that i want to use to generate a JSON object that contains data from different models. The viewset for the model is:

```
class InvoiceView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    
    def list(self, request):
        cart_id = request.data["cart_id"]
        
        shop = Shop.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
        cart = ShoppingSession.objects.get(id=cart_id)
        cart_items = CartItem.objects.filter(session=cart_id)
        paymentmethod = PaymentMethod.objects.get(id=cart.payment_method.id)
        
        Invoice = namedtuple('Receipt',('shopname','cart', 'cartitems', 'paymentmethod'))
        
        invoice = Invoice(
                shopname = shop,
                cart = cart, 
                cartitems = cart_items, 
                paymentmethod = paymentmethod
                
            )
      
        serializer = ReceiptSerializer(Invoice)
        
        return Response(serializer.data,)
```

The serializers used are:

```
class ShopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Shop
        exclude = ['is_staff', 'is_active', 'start_date']

class ReceiptSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    
    shopname = ShopSerializer()
    cart = ShoppingSessionSerializer()
    cartitems = CartItemSerializer(many=True)
    paymentmethod = PaymentMethodSerializer()
```

When the url is run and a GET request is executed. An error is generated that looks like this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sean/anaconda3/envs/skakey/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/sean/anaconda3/envs/skakey/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/sean/anaconda3/envs/skakey/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sean/anaconda3/envs/skakey/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 125, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sean/anaconda3/envs/skakey/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/sean/anaconda3/envs/skakey/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/sean/anaconda3/envs/skakey/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/home/sean/anaconda3/envs/skakey/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sean/Development/SKAKEY/shops/views.py", line 280, in list
    return Response(serializer.data,)
  File "/home/sean/anaconda3/envs/skakey/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 555, in data
    ret = super().data
  File "/home/sean/anaconda3/envs/skakey/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 253, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "/home/sean/anaconda3/envs/skakey/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 522, in to_representation
    ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
  File "/home/sean/anaconda3/envs/skakey/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 509, in to_representation
    attribute = field.get_attribute(instance)
  File "/home/sean/anaconda3/envs/skakey/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 490, in get_attribute
    raise type(exc)(msg)
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `first_name` on serializer `ShopSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `_tuplegetter` instance.
Original exception text was: '_collections._tuplegetter' object has no attribute 'first_name'.
```

How are you supposed to user multiple serializers in one serializer class for this kind of custom use-case?

Comment: Please post the full traceback error.

Comment: Done. How would recommend implementing such a custom serializer.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need the `namedtuple`, you can initialize the serializer as

```
receipt_serializer = ReceiptSerializer(data={
    'shop': Shop.objects.get(id=request.user.id).__dict__,
    'cart': ShoppingSession.objects.get(id=cart_id).__dict__,
    'cart_items': CartItem.objects.filter(session=cart_id).__dict__,
    'paymentmethod': PaymentMethod.objects.get(id=cart.payment_method.id).__dict__})
```

Then call `receipt_serializer.is_valid()`, and you can then get the output from `receipt_serializer.data`